# Install a specific version of EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

I want to install an old version of EF, but I don't know the version number. Can we do it in Nuget?
Using manage console is always getting the latest one not a desired one.

I want to look up it from a drop down menu and select one. Using command line is sort of foolish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see all versions of the EntityFramework NuGet package using the Package Manager console you can run:

```
Get-Package -Filter EntityFramework -ListAvailable -AllVersions | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq 'EntityFramework' }
```

If you want to use a GUI then take a look at [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/). There is an option to show all versions of the NuGet packages.

Alternatively you could browse the NuGet package versions on the [NuGet website](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework).