# Compatibility.... Downgrade a project from vs2012 to vs2008

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, compatibility

I have a project created on my own pc with Visual Studio 2012, initialy with Entity Framework 4.5

I made it compatible with Entity Framework 3.5 because the computers where the application will run are Vista ones.. ( O_o )

After lot of debug, creating a new db compatible, creating the model of the new database, I finally performed this first downgrade and it's working on my computer with Entity Framework 3.5 as we can see in this screenshot: http://imagik.fr/view/128976

I can start the .exe on my computer without any problem. I have modified the App.Config connection string to give the right path for the database on their computer and then have tried, just insta crash when it works on mine..

Finally I have installed vs 2008 on one vista computer and I can't import my vs 2012 project, too recent. If I create a new project on 2008 and just create the classes with copy/paste, add libraries and references, I have a problem with my DB. the database.mdf version is 706 and can't be upper than 655.

I'm completely lost with these compatibilities problems... I know we can upgrate a 2008 project to 2012, but is it possible in the other way? Should it be a solution?

If not, what am I supposed to do? They told me "free technology", finally it isn't free at all.....

If anyone already met those kind of problems..

Thanks in advance for your help.

ps: If you need other informations, I can give screens, just ask me.

ps°2: I know there is a lot of problems like mine on the web and on StackOverflow, but I have already done what they said (Edit the properties of the project and make its EntityFramework to 3.5, adding the .csproj of the 2012 on a blank vs 2008 project, etc.)

Comment: You don't need to convert your project to VS2008 format to do this. You can target any version of .NET Framework back to 2.0 in VS2012 (right-click project, Properties, Application, Target Framework).

Comment: Who told you "They told me "free technology", and what do you mean by that? And does EF 4.5 not install on Vista? Looks like 6.1 is latest version now.

Comment: The version of EF that you target is determined by what you install using Nuget, so remove the newer EF and downgrade using Nuget. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524748/install-a-specific-version-of-entityframework) on how to find the right version and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956925/how-to-install-entityframework-5-0-and-other-older-versions-from-nuget)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm on stage crashmstr, it's where I work they told me I can use what I want to. Moreover, it's a huge enterprise and they won't install EF 4.5. They could, but they won't.

@tianvh thanks for your links, I'll do this and see if it works.

Comment: I have the 6.1.1 version with the first link command. Is  `install-package entityframework -version 3.5.0 -project XXXXX` is possible? I saw it started at 4.1.10715 ?

Comment: The first version of EF was 3.5 and it was bundled with .NET Framework 3.5 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx)), so remove any EF Nuget packages from your project and add a reference to EF from the GAC